# Control multiply form created via Qt designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am working on simple project which contained multiply windows or forms. I created on Qt designer 3 forms Form1, Form2, Form3.

I found how to control 2 forms by using one of the form like a main and modify generated via PyQt5 files. However I believe there are should be a way to do it via main function without modifying automated codes.
If any one have working example how to it would be much appreciate!

Comment: Two simple suggestions: first of all, **never** edit the files generated from `pyuic` (read how to [use Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to correctly use them); edit your question by providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (please, read that link and follow its suggestions!) so that we can understand your issues and actually help you with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I found one example which actually simply explains how to do it! [Multiple Windows with Python QT-Designer ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHsC6WJsK-U)